# Set HTTP proxy settings for a WiFi access point using ADB on android

Tags: android, adb

I need to automate the setting of a WiFi access point proxy settings.
Currently the only way I can get this to happen is to set it by hand in the advanced options of the access point settings.

I have in place a method to add and connect to the access point using wpa_supplicant, but I can't figure out how to set the HTTP proxy settings.

Answer (score 5):

I have created an app that will allow you to do exactly what you are asking. I developed it for use in my own automation setup and it has been working reliably for me so far. You can look at the source and download the apk from [github](https://github.com/jpkrause/AndroidProxySetter). All you have to do is install it on the device you want to automate proxy changes and then run an adb command to have the app set your proxy settings. More details on how to use it are in the README on github.

Comment: This solution is limited to Android 5.x and lower.

Comment: This has worked on Genymotion Andorid 6.0 and 7.0 without a problem. Maybe @methodsignature was right at that time since a new APK was released by J. P. Krause.